# search trough shell aliases; what's your way of doing it?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, iterm2

I have a lot of aliases in .bashrc. I installed bash_it which adds a bunch more. sometimes I can't remember that for example `bin` is the alias for `brew install` so I do a `alias | grep brew` to see all that's somehow aliasing something regarding brew.

Is there a faster/smarter way to look for a particular alias that you can't remember exactly?

Otherwise I'm tempted to create another one: `alias searchlistofaliases = 'alias | grep'`

Comment: yeah, but it's `bin` that I don't remember, I just know I have one for `brew install` but then I don't remember it was `bin`

Comment: @anubhava: I think he meant the other way around.

Comment: @Tom: I don't think there's any other way since the `alias` is defined by you, it could be any name. There isn't any other way other than checking what name you chose with `alias | grep <>`

Comment: probably so yes... guess I'll do the alias above to lookup the alias I just don't remember atm :)

Comment: yeah, that's the way so I'll add one more alias to the ones I have

`sa@mbp: ~/from_wks  alias | wc -l
     282
sa@mbp: ~/from_wks`

Comment: If you have more aliases than you can remember, then they aren't really doing their job, which is to make it easier to run common commands. Using your example, if you don't remember that `bin` is `brew install`, then you probably aren't really running `brew install` enough for it to be worth defining an alias for it.

Comment: `bin` just came in with installing bash-it three days ago, that's why I'm still getting used to those new aliases and needed a faster way to look them up